# Problem with change url for all subpages (.htaccess)

Tags: urls, mod-rewrite, add-submenu-page

Im looking for someone who will knowing the main code

I have subpages with ugly names http://grimlord.eu/index_pl.php?src=home
How cut it for this url grimlord.eu/**start**

[image]
[image]

Pls tell me how?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index_pl.php?src=home=$1&subpage=$2 [L,QSA]
```